# 'as' typecasting to not permit subset types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Why is it that, for string union type `T = "A" | "B"`, the following is a valid assignment?

`const x = ["A", "C"] as Array<T>`?

Trying to understand the `as` operator here. The following are not valid:

`const x = ["C"] as Array<T>`

`const x: Array<T> = ["A", "C"]`

So I'm guessing that the `as` operator enforces that the type of the object being cast is a subset of the cast type. Is there a way to type `T` such that my first example is not valid using `as`?

Comment: is the code to define T, `type T = "A" | "B";` ?

Comment: The term "cast" is a loaded one and means different things to different people; it's best avoided in TypeScript.  What TypeScript has is known as a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  The rule for whether `expr as Type` is allowable is that `typeof expr` and `Type` are "related to each other", which is *roughly* if either is assignable to the other, but there are definitely other heuristics involved, see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14156#issuecomment-299965629) for example.

Comment: I'm really confused by the phrasing of your question, though; you want us to define `T` such that `const x = ["A", "C"] as Array<T>` is an error?  Okay, `type T = number`.  That's presumably not what you want, right?  So what are you looking for?

Comment: Oh, the rule is actually known as "comparable to" (instead of "related to"), as implemented in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5517.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry for the misleading type name. T isn't a generic here but a type literal `T = "A" | "B"`. So `["A", "C"]` should not be an `Array<T>` because `"C"` is not in `T`

Comment: I didn't think `T` was generic (although it's an unfortunate name choice, since the name implies generics).  But your question is literally "Is there a way to type `T` such that my first example is not valid using `as`"?  That implies you want us to change `T`, right?  If not, can you rephrase the question so as to be as clear as possible?

Comment: You are right that `["A", "C"]` is not an `Array<"A" | "B">`.  If you try to use a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) to say that it is, the compiler will warn you.  But if you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) it won't.  I'm not sure why that matters so much to you; type assertions are not guaranteed to be type safe... you should only use them when you know more about a type than the compiler does.

Comment: If you use them to intentionally lie to the compiler like `["A", "C"] as Array<"A" | "B">`, then it's your fault if bad things happen later.  Type assertions are when the developer takes some responsibility for type safety away from the compiler.  Even if `["A", "C"] as Array<"A" | "B">` were to be an error, something like `["A", "C"] as any as Array<"A" | "B">` would not be.  Type assertions let you lie to the compiler, and as such, should be used sparingly.  Why are you using `as` at all here? Perhaps you're thinking of type assertions as "casting" in some runtime sense?